# What does “clear-cut title favorites” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[image: Stephen A. Smith' statement about Andre Iguodala]

> If Andre Iguodala goes to the Lakers, I believe they would become the **clear-cut title favorites**!

I do not understand the meaning of **clear-cut**, **title** and **favorites** here.

I had checked those words in dictionaries. I do not understand the relationship among those words(clear-cut, title and favorites). Firstly, title should be a noun? clear-cut should be a adjective? It is used as an adjective to modify title? Favorite is used as an adjective to modify title? But why favorite has “s”?

Answer (score 3):

[clear-cut](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clear-cut):

> clear or obvious without needing any proof

[title](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/title):

> the position you get by beating all other competitors in a sports competition

[favorite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/favorite):

> a competitor likely to win

So, including the context, the sentence states that with the addition of Andre Iguodala, it has become clear that the Lakers are most likely to win the title, i.e., competition.